# JPQL query sometimes not returning expected result

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have a weird issue with a JPQL query showing some inconsistent behaviour. I wrote the following method, from which I expect to get a list of all activities for the given employee, which overlap the given TimePeriod object.

```
    public List<Activity> getAllActivities(Employee employee,
        TimePeriod timePeriod) throws DatasetException {
    if (employee == null || timePeriod == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    try {
        final Query query = em
                .createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT a from Activity a INNER JOIN a.employeeTimePeriods e"
                        + " INNER JOIN e.timePeriods t WHERE "
                        + " e.employee = ?1"
                        + " AND a.time.day = ?2"
                        + " AND ?3 < t.endTime"
                        + " AND ?4 > t.startTime"
                        + " ORDER BY a.time.startTime");
        query.setParameter(1, employee);
        query.setParameter(2, timePeriod.getDay());
        query.setParameter(3, timePeriod.getStartTime());
        query.setParameter(4, timePeriod.getEndTime());
        return query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format(
                "Exception while getting all activities of employee %s, "
                        + "which overlap time period %s.", employee,
                timePeriod), e);
        throw new DatasetException(
                String.format(
                        "Error while getting all activities of employee %s, "
                                + "which overlap time period %s: "
                                + e.getMessage(), employee, timePeriod));
    }
}
```

Furthermore I created some test cases: 
I have one employee, who participates in two activities:

- Mondays from 10:00 to 10:45
- Mondays from 10:45 to 11:30

And I have a TimePeriod object with the day set to monday, the starttime set to 10:00 and the endtime set to 12:00.

Now I would expect to always get both previously listed activities from my method, but there is the problem. I sometimes(!) only get the first, at other times the test case succeeds. I have some more test cases for this method, which never failed (but I just noticed that above test case is the only one, which has to select two activities).

I also have the same test case for rooms (except that the TimePeriod object's starttime is 09:00 there), which never failed. But because there is a difference in the queries - in the query for rooms I was able to use `MEMBER OF` - I am guessing that there could be a problem with the joins.

For the sake of completeness the query for rooms:

```
            final Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Activity a WHERE"
                + " ?1 MEMBER OF a.rooms AND a.time.day = ?2"
                + " AND ?3 < a.time.endTime AND ?4 > a.time.startTime"
                + " ORDER BY a.time.startTime");
        query.setParameter(1, room);
        query.setParameter(2, timePeriod.getDay());
        query.setParameter(3, timePeriod.getStartTime());
        query.setParameter(4, timePeriod.getEndTime());
```

Has anyone any suggestion regarding a solution to my problem?

Comment: Try turning logging on to see the query that is generated and the parameters used: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging  This will help determine what might be different in the failure case from the success.

Comment: Thanks. Just did that. There is only one little difference in the order of select parameters in both queries, but that really should not have any influence on the query execution.

Comment: Can you show the parameters used in relation to the generated SQL in the working case vs the non working case?

Comment: I also have this problem with another query related to activities and employees now and I have absolutely no clue, why this happens. The queries in the case of success and failure look nearly the same, only a little difference in the beginning:
success: `SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.DAY, t1.DURATION, t1.ENDTIME, t1.STARTTIME, t1.MEETINGTYPE_ID, t1.PROJECTTYPE_ID, t1.LESSONTYPE_ID`

---

failure: `SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.DAY, t1.DURATION, t1.ENDTIME, t1.STARTTIME, t1.LESSONTYPE_ID, t1.PROJECTTYPE_ID, t1.MEETINGTYPE_ID`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your query returns wrong results sometimes (for the same inputs?) but I do think you could simplify the query and maybe have an easier time at debugging.

```
select
    distinct a
from
    Activity a inner join a.employeeTimePeriods e
    inner join e.timePeriods t
where
    e.employee = ?1 and
    a.time.day = ?2 and
    t.endTime >= ?3 and
    t.startTime <= ?4
```

Where ?1 = room, ?2 = day, ?3 = start time, and ?4 = end time.

Essentially, what you are asking for is "Show me activities for a specific employee, on the given day, that end after or on my window start and start before or on my window end.

So for your Activities of:

- Activity 1 = Mondays from 10:00 to 10:45
- Activity 2 = Mondays from 10:45 to 11:30

And a time period of: 10:00 to 12:00, it should return both of those records because:

- Activity 1

  - t.endTime is 10:45 which is greater than 10:00 AND
  - t.startTime is 10:00 and is before 12:00.
- Activity 2

  - t.endTime is 11:30 which is greater than 10:00 AND
  - t.startTime is 10:45 and is before 12:00.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It seems that I have thought a little bit too complicated, would not have noticed that without your remark, so thanks!
It actually does not solve the problem with the test failing sometimes as I had to notice after a few test runs.
Before this test case runs an init method, which creates always the same database state. So yes, it does return wrong result for the same input. I already debugged the project until I saw, that the list size was 1, aborted and took a look into the database. Everything looked as expected. It is pretty confusing...

Comment: One little annotation: I actually did not want to get activities, which start on the window end or end on the window start, so I used < and > for the simplified queries.

Comment: Ah yeah, I should have caught that. Glad it (kind of) helped.